# How to move several files in diferent directories to one unique directory?

Tags: actions-on-google

I have 220 directories, each one with 2 files inside. all the files have the same termination (*.fq.gz). I want to move all these files to one unique directory.

I think I could do that with a shell loop, but I don't have an idea of how to do that.

Comment: Show us whatever you tried.

Comment: What does this have to do with actions-on-google?